# Would it be possible that I forgot something?

Tags: c++

```
string str;
int i = 0, counter = 0;
cin >> str;
do
{
    if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')counter++;
    cout << "Yes";
    i++;

}while(str[i] != '\0');
```

A piece of code that takes a string from a user and outputs one single "Yes" if there are any capitals otherwise output nothing. This is from my test and I did not completely fulfill what was require in the instruction.

It works, but then when I type like "HHi" it will output "YesYes" when it should only be "Yes".

How can I ensure it only prints one "Yes" when it finds any amount of capitals?

Comment: Instead of incrementing a counter, just output Yes and break out of the loop when you find a capital. You're never checking the counter anyway.

Comment: Also, uppercase letters are not contiguous for all character sets (there can be characters that are not letters between `'A'` and `'Z'`).   You're better off using the standard function `isupper()` from standard header `<cctype>`.

Comment: Subject of this question totally has no meaning in context of programming

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative answer to @Jonathan's answer. Simply you can achieve the same answer without using a break statement.

```
string str; 
int i = 0, counter = 0;
cin >> str;
while(str[i] != '\0')
{
    if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
       counter++;
    i++;
}
if(counter > 0)
    cout << "Yes";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should output "Yes" inside your if statement and immediately break the while loop, e.g.:

```
string str; 
int i = 0;
cin >> str;
while(str[i] != '\0')
{
    if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z'){
        cout << "Yes";
        break;
    }
    i++;

}
```

(and it seems your code will break when the input is empty string.)

Comment: is it also possible to do it without using the break? Thanks!

Comment: yes, have your counter inside the if statement, and after the loop, check if `counter > 0`, if yes, print "Yes".

Comment: not really sure, but there are a lot of programming courses in the Internet that you can try (KhanAcademy, coursera to name a few). good luck!